# Call a javascript function from a link. All possible methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div ~ id is `slider` I want it to animate/hide when a link is clicked. More precisely I want to toggle it open and close from a link.

## jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#toggleslider").click(function () {
    $(this).hide("#slider", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

## link

```
<li><a id="toggleslider" href="javascript:void(0);">toggle</a></li>
```

Comment: Make sure to have your code in a `$(function() {...})` so the dom is loaded before you assign event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [.slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

```
$("#toggleslider").click(function () {
    $('#slider').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

***[The live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/5gzKJ/)***

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery toggle() function to toggle it from visible to invisible (and vice-versa).  Take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

It should be the same syntax, only instead of calling "hide", change it to "toggle".

EDIT: Your syntax might not be totally correct.  Try this.

```
$("#slider").toggle(1000);
```

Comment: thanks for your input - I tried your suggestion and xdazz's - but it just wont work and I'm not doing anything wrong. I have no idea why its not working.